# Which one is better Ubuntu 12.04.3 (32 bit) or (64 bit)?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

i am going to Download Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, and i will Burn it to a DVD...

i try it with USB and it was 64 bit.. and gives error in middle.. so this time i am using a DVD maybe it might work...

But i dont know which bit to use 32 bit Or 64 bit... but i am thinkng maybe it gives the error again with 64 bit

i have 4GB Ram...
and Windows 8 PRO 64 bit

and i Love Ubuntu alot.... its just Amazing and Fast...
and i just Try (Try it Without Installation) and it was Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

- If your architecture supports 64 bit,it was better to install ubuntu 12.04.3 64 bit.Try to create live-usb through unetbootin software.
- Error comes because of installation medium or software used to make bootable usb and not because of ubuntu 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you hardware, which either supports 64bit or does not. You can type **uname -m** when you try Ubuntu Live (i.e. without installing)... if it shows **x86_64** then you should install the 64 bit version of Linux, otherwise you have to install the 32 bit version.

Also, as Raj said it seems to be a problem with the installation medium or the software, especially since you are using Windows 8 64 bit on the same machine.

It is important that you use the right software to create/prepare the USB stick with the Ubuntu iso. Have a look [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) how to do so properly in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 64x that means your Processor supports 64 bit architecture.

This Ubuntu system architecture does not makes any difference for speed but it does  matters for Compatibility.

To check your current Architecture on windows , right click on **My Computer** and then click on System Properties , in that you will all the information like Architecture and other information.

Suppose you are having 32 bit and all the hardware drivers working properly then you can have a try on 32x but if its 64x and working properly then you must install Ubuntu amd64 .iso.

For more compatibility Information click [Here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/hardware-supported.html) 
After that for making bootable DVD [click here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), and for making bootable USB instructions [click here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), the best software for making Bootable USB Stick use Universal USB Installer , you can download it from [here.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Hope it helped you and all your doubts are clear here.